# Smoothly Play video from URL in recyclerview

Tags: android, url, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I tried to play videos in Recyclerview but its not working properly . For this  I have used : https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager.

Can anyone pls tell me alternate solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Modify it as per your need

```
    @BindView(R.id.rv_home) RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestForRead();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        setRecyclerView();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            new VideosAsync(getContext()).execute();
        else
            requestForRead();

        return view;
    }

    private void setRecyclerView(){
        LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new SnapHelperOneByOne();
        linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }


    //get list of videos
    private List<String> getAllMedia() {
        HashSet<String> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection
                , null, null, null);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                videoItemHashSet.add(path);
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(videoItemHashSet);
    }


    private void requestForRead(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    }

    public class VideosAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private Context context;
        private List<String> videoList;

        public VideosAsync(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            videoList.addAll(getAllMedia());
            return videoList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> videos) {
            HomeAdapter adapter = new HomeAdapter(videos, context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }
    }
}
```

SnapHelperOneByOne

```
public class SnapHelperOneByOne extends LinearSnapHelper{

    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY){

        if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        final View currentView = findSnapView(layoutManager);

        if( currentView == null ){
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        final int currentPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(currentView);

        if (currentPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        return currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> videoList;
    private Context context;

    public HomeAdapter(List<String> videoList, Context context) {
        this.videoList = videoList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_video_home, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Uri path = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
        setVideoView(holder, path);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.video_view_home) FullScreenVideoView fullScreenVideoView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    private void setVideoView(ViewHolder holder, Uri videoPath){
        holder.fullScreenVideoView.seekTo(100);
        holder.fullScreenVideoView.setVideoURI(videoPath);
        holder.fullScreenVideoView.requestFocus();
        holder.fullScreenVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
            mp.setLooping(true);

            //Set the surface holder height to the screen dimensions
            holder.fullScreenVideoView.start();
        });
    }
}
```

Row layout for adapter

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.codencolors.myapplication.helper.FullScreenVideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view_home"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_message"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_forward"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Manifest permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```